# Scala extract CassandraRow from RDD spark streaming

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a following code :-

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
val records = kafkaStream.map(_._2)

records.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  {
    rdd.collect().foreach(a =>
      {
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val jValue = parse(a)
        val record = jValue.extract[historyevent]
        println("JSON String" + a.toString())

        val history_gpsdt = record.gpsdt //"2017-04-12 00:25:10"
        val history_latitude = record.latitude //6.854678
        val history_longitude = record.longitude //78.583751

        val rss = sc.cassandraTable("db", "table").select("imei", "date", "gpsdt").where("imei=? and date=?", record.imei, record.date)
// some more set of statements
      }
   }
 }
```

So, here I'm getting set of JSON strings from Kafka Streaming from which I'am extracting each row one by one and then performing some logic on data . Hence, I just want to understand whether I'm using optimal way or we can more optimise it. Please suggest. Thanks,

Comment: That's kind of an open-ended question... typically SO is for more specific questiosn

Comment: Hi, @StevenBlack to be more specific my query is like I'm using records.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  {
    rdd.collect().foreach(a =>
      { }} So , is it nice way to extract row from RDD or I can have it in single loop to make my program faster .